# Visual studio for mac - Enable default conulttent items

Tags: c#, macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to work in a asp.net core project that is currently working fine in VS 2017.

I get the code from Git & restore all package from Nuget correctly.

When I try to start or build the application I have an error in the Microsoft.Net.Sdk.defaultItems.target of the last available version of .Net core for mac.

Code targeted :

```
<!-- Default content items are enabled by the Web SDK, not the .NET SDK, but we check it here for simplicity -->
    <CheckForDuplicateItems
      Items="@(Content)"
      ItemName="Content"
      DefaultItemsEnabled="$(EnableDefaultItems)"
      DefaultItemsOfThisTypeEnabled="$(EnableDefaultContentItems)"
      PropertyNameToDisableDefaultItems="EnableDefaultContentItems"
      MoreInformationLink="$(DefaultItemsMoreInformationLink)"
      ContinueOnError="$(CheckForDuplicateItemsContinueOnError)">
      <Output TaskParameter="DeduplicatedItems" ItemName="DeduplicatedContentItems" />
    </CheckForDuplicateItems>
```

Error (this is a quick translation from french) :

> Duplicated "Content" elements were included. .Net SDK automatically
>   include "Content" elements from your project directory. You can delete
>   this elements from you project or set the property
>   "EnableDefaultContentItems" to false. If you want to include the
>   changes in your project file blablabla...

Of course I delete all the duplicated content but I still have the error.

I someone already face to this error...

EDIT : The file are only duplicated in Visual Studio for mac each time I launch my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking on the repo of .Net core SDK, I find that the

> "EnableDefaultContentItems"

needs to be added to the `.csproj` of the project that raise the error.

Problem solved